# Still wrong to start the name of a user stored procedure with sp_?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, stored-procedures

One of my co-workers named a stored procedure in our SQL Server 2008 R2 database `sp_something`. When I saw this, I immediately thought: "That is WRONG!" and started searching my bookmarks for [this online article](http://www.sqlmag.com/article/tsql3/should-i-use-the-sp_-prefix-for-procedure-names-) that explains why it is wrong, so I could provide my co-worker with an explanation.

In the article (by [Brian Moran](http://www.sqlmag.com/author/5086182/BrianMoran)) it is explained that giving the stored procedure an **sp_** prefix makes SQL Server look at the master database for a compiled plan. Because the `sp_sproc` doesn't reside there, SQL Server will recompile the procedure (and needs an exclusive compile lock for that, causing performance problems).

The following example is given in the article to show the difference between two procedures:

```
USE tempdb;
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Select1 AS SELECT 1;
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_Select1 AS SELECT 1;
GO

EXEC dbo.sp_Select1;
GO

EXEC dbo.Select1;
GO
```

You run this, then open the Profiler (add the Stored Procedures -> `SP:CacheMiss` event) and run the stored procedures again. You're supposed to see a difference between the two stored procedures: the `sp_Select1` stored procedure will generate one more `SP:CacheMiss` event than the `Select1` stored procedure (the article references **SQL Server 7.0** and **SQL Server 2000**.)

When I run the example in my SQL Server 2008 R2 environment, I get the same amount of `SP:CacheMiss` events for both procedures (both in tempdb and in another test database).

So I am wondering:

- Can I have done something wrong in my execution of the example?
- <strike>Is the 'do not name a user `sproc sp_something`' adagium still valid in newer versions of SQL Server?</strike>
- If so, is there a good example that shows its validity in SQL Server 2008 R2?

Thanks a lot for your thoughts on this!

**EDIT**

I found [Creating Stored Procedures (Database Engine)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) on msdn for SQL Server 2008 R2, which answers my second question:

> We recommend that you do not create any stored procedures using sp_ as
>   a prefix. SQL Server uses the sp_ prefix to designate system stored
>   procedures. The name you choose may conflict with some future system
>   procedure. [...]

Nothing is mentioned there about *performance problems* caused by using the `sp_` prefix though. I'd love to know if that's still the case or if they fixed it after SQL Server 2000.

Comment: I did look at this before and found a negligible performance difference which I put down to slightly greater overhead of resolving the `sp_` versions (needs to check in both master and user databases because it prioritises system procs in `master` ->  procs in user DB -> non system procs in `master`)

Comment: What benefit do you see for prefixing a stored procedure with `sp_`? This is about as useful as prefixing a table with `tbl`. Why make the system search master first (even if it's at negligible or no performance difference) to allow you to use this meaningless naming convention?

Comment: @AaronBertrand: to be honest, I see no benefit _at all_ in prefixing sprocs with sp_, only disadvantages, and I would never prefix them this way myself. But I want all the arguments I can get to convince my co-workers to not do it either.

Comment: Yeah, tbl is useless, but I still love using it. Must be my OCD kicking in. Now get off my lawn.

Comment: @Josien ok, a quick analogy: sometimes when you do cartwheels it hurts - even if only a little. If you tell your doctor about this, he's probably going to tell you to stop doing cartwheels. :-)

Comment: @Josien also, your co-workers should be coming with arguments *for* making a naming scheme more complicated. Get them to explain why `dbo.sp_Author_Rename` is better than `dbo.Author_Rename`. I can't think of a single thing that makes sense.

Comment: @AaronBertrand The explanation probably comes down to something like:  "We read (20+ years ago) that Hungarian Notation was a good thing (while completely failing to understand what Simonyi was actually suggesting be encoded), so we're just following Best Practices (DM)".  (DM = DerpMark)

Comment: It seems the culprit was not one of my co-workers, but an external database application supplier. We will notify them of their Bad Practices :-)

Comment: In my experience, first one there gets the set these kind of conventions. In reality it almost certainly won't cause problems to have these prefixes, even though it makes no sense and gives no benefit. But if the corporate standard has been set - even if only by one person - it's pretty hard to shake it off.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This is fairly easy to test yourself. Let's create two very simple procedures:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_mystuff
AS
  SELECT 'x';
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.mystuff
AS
  SELECT 'x';
GO
```

Now let's build a wrapper that executes them a number of times, with and without the schema prefix:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.wrapper_sp1
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @i INT = 1;
    WHILE @i <= 1000
    BEGIN
      EXEC sp_mystuff;
      SET @i += 1;
    END
END
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.wrapper_1
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @i INT = 1;
    WHILE @i <= 1000
    BEGIN
      EXEC mystuff;
      SET @i += 1;
    END
END
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.wrapper_sp2
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @i INT = 1;
    WHILE @i <= 1000
    BEGIN
      EXEC dbo.sp_mystuff;
      SET @i += 1;
    END
END
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.wrapper_2
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @i INT = 1;
    WHILE @i <= 1000
    BEGIN
      EXEC dbo.mystuff;
      SET @i += 1;
    END
END
GO
```

Results:

[image]

Conclusions:

- using sp_ prefix is slower
- leaving out schema prefix is slower

The more important question: why would you *want* to use the sp_ prefix? What do your co-workers expect to *gain* from doing so? This shouldn't be about you having to prove that this is worse, it should be about them justifying adding the same three-letter prefix to every single stored procedure in the system. I fail to see the benefit.

Also I performed some pretty extensive testing of this pattern in the following blog post:

http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Comment: Note, these results are on SQL Server 2012. But you can perform the same tests in your environment.

Comment: "What do your co-works expect to gain from doing so" see also [Hungarian Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation). Basically, it's a 90s thing for the most part. Also, at my past job the standard was to prefix every stored procedure with `sp_` so that they could be differentiated from other things and no name conflicts... I had no idea this performance problem existed with it.

Comment: Great example, thanks Aaron. I'm still testing it on 2008 R2 (and probably testing it the wrong way, cause 'dbo.wrapper_sp1' and 'dbo.wrapper_sp2' seem significantly faster than the other two right now).

Answer (score 14):

> We recommend that you do not create any stored procedures using sp_ as a prefix. SQL Server uses the sp_ prefix to designate system stored procedures. The name you choose may conflict with some future system procedure. [...]
>
> Nothing is mentioned there about performance problems caused by using the sp_ prefix though. I'd love to know if that's still the case or if they fixed it after SQL Server 2000.

As Martin Smith's simple comment shows - yes, if you have a stored procedure with an `sp_` prefix - the SQL Server query executor will **always** check in the `master` database first to see if a stored procedure (marked as a system stored procedure) by that name exists.

And if it exists, that system stored procedure from the `master` database always prevails and will be executed instead of your own.

So yes - it still stands: **don't use** the `sp_` prefix.

Comment: Simple to test. `CREATE PROC dbo.sp_helptext  AS SELECT 1` then try `EXEC dbo.sp_helptext`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, very useful addition on the prevalence of `master` sp's.

Answer (score 2):

A better test is to write a query that requires full optimization since that is likely a better reflection of what the proc you're writing is doing.  I wrapped the following query in an SP and repeated your test and got the same results.

```
select * from Person.BusinessEntity b
inner join Person.BusinessEntityAddress ba on b.BusinessEntityID = ba.BusinessEntityID
inner join Person.Address a on ba.AddressID = a.AddressID
```

I got the same number of cache miss and hit events in both cases and in both cases the plan was added to the cache.  I also ran both procs several times and there was no consistent difference in CPU time or elapsed time reported by dm_exec_query_stats.

The other concern is that since "sp_" procs can be executed from master that you may get a copy of the proc that was run into master instead of the DB you're working in but a quick test will show that's not the case.  However, if the proc gets dropped from the DB you're working in and a copy exists in master then it will be executed which could be a problem if it's an old version.  If this is a concern I wouldn't use "sp_" to name the proc.

Comment: Interesting finds, thanks! I'll use your example in combination with [Aaron's example](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/25367/5147) to run some more tests.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue has to do when you do not specify the fully qualified object name. So, "EXEC sp_something" will check master first, but "EXEC dbname.dbo.sp_something" will never go to master first.

The lesson, if I recall, is to always use the fully qualified name.

Comment: Don't think that makes any difference. `EXEC MyDB.dbo.sp_helptext 'sp_helptext'` still uses the one from `master` even if there is one in the user database. AFAIK it checks both locations and will use the one from `master` if it exists and is marked as a system object.

Comment: @MartinSmith on 2012 I could not coerce the master version to be executed (though my tests there did show that there is *something* going on), unless I dropped the local copy (in which case `MyDB.dbo.sp_foo` still executed the master version). I don't have 2008/2008 R2 right now to confirm where this behavior changed.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - Ah, interesting I did my test on 2008 R2.

Comment: Also note that if a local procedure is not found and one is found in master, the latter will be executed, and does *not* need to be marked as a system object for this to happen. And in 2012 at least, whether or not the master copy is marked as a system object, does not change the behavior - with or without local db/schema prefix, the local copy is always executed unless it doesn't exist.

Comment: If you create a procedure in your database with the same name as a system stored procedure, you will never be able to run your procedure. `create proc dbo.sp_help …` in your database - `exec sp_help` and `exec dbo.sp_help` and `exec MyDB.dbo.sp_help` will all run the system stored procedure. Tested just now in SQL Server 2012 Dev edition (v 11.0.2100.60).

Comment: @GreenstoneWalker this is true, I should have clarified: I was talking about user procedures with the sp_ prefix (marked as system objects or not), not true ms-shipped system procedures. The danger, of course, is that you could create a local procedure named sp_foo and your behavior will change if Microsoft later introduces a system procedure with the same name. So the argument is still: *NEVER* use the sp_ prefix.

Comment: Oops, I should have clarified that my comment was aimed at the suggested answer. SQLRockstar's comment "EXEC dbname.dbo.sp_something will never go to master first." is incorrect.

Comment: Agreed, it looks as if the missing piece for me was having something marked as a system object. Apparently 'sp_' tells SQL Server that it is likely a system object. I like Aaron's test scenario. However, a difference in duration of 80ms for 1,000 executions is not what I would consider a significant amount of overhead. The extra CPU ticks (about 10%) is something I would note.